# Template not working, not showing anything on screen

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm having really trouble understanding templates and how to use them and re-use them across my App. I have defined two style templates in a resource dictionary, then in my page load them in the correct control and set the style to the resource in dictionary, but nothing showing in screen, nothing at all. I have the control working in another page but I am trying to make it re-usable, code:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Style x:Key="CustomListBox" TargetType="ListBox">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded"
                    Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" />
        </Style>
        <ScrollViewer x:Key="Scroller">
            <ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility>
                Auto
            </ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                <ItemsPresenter/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="CustomExpander" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                <DockPanel>
                    <ToggleButton
                        DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                        Background="Teal"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        Foreground="WhiteSmoke"
                        FontSize="12"
                        Name="Header"
                        Padding="1"
                        >
                        <ToggleButton.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ToggleButton.Template>
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <ContentPresenter
                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                        Name="ExpandSite"
                        Visibility="Collapsed"
                        DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>        
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Implementation:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Neotek.Contabilidad.UI.Views.AdminView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Neotek.Contabilidad.UI.Views"

         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="600">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Visual Resources/MenuDesplegableRD.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListBox Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource CustomListBox}" Background="Yellow" Width="200" Height="200">
           <Expander Width="200" Height="200" Background="Violet"
                     Style="{StaticResource CustomExpander}">
            <Expander.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="Administrar Cuentas"
                               Foreground="White" />
            </Expander.Header>
            <WrapPanel>
                <Label Margin="20,5,5,5" Foreground="white" Content="Nueva Cuenta"/>
                <Label Margin="20,5,5,5" Foreground="white" Content="--------------"/>
                <Label Margin="20,5,5,5" Foreground="white" Content="---------------"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </Expander>
        <Expander Style="{StaticResource CustomExpander}">
            <Expander.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Administrar Cuentas"
                               Foreground="White" />
            </Expander.Header>
            <WrapPanel>
                <Label Margin="20,5,5,5" Foreground="white" Content="Nueva Cuenta"/>
                <Label Margin="20,5,5,5" Foreground="white" Content="--------------"/>
                <Label Margin="20,5,5,5" Foreground="white" Content="---------------"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </Expander>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I have this working:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded"

       Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Resources>
            <ListBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ListBox.Template>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Expander Background="OliveDrab">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <BulletDecorator>
                        <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                            <Image Width="60" Height="64" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0"  Text="Administrar Cuentas" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="White" />
                    </BulletDecorator>
                </Expander.Header>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <Label Margin="20,5,5,5" Foreground="white" Content="Nueva Cuenta"/>
                    <Label Margin="20,5,5,5" Foreground="white" Content="--------------"/>
                    <Label Margin="20,5,5,5" Foreground="white" Content="---------------"/>
                </WrapPanel>
            </Expander>

            <Expander Background="OrangeRed">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <BulletDecorator>
                        <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                            <Image Width="64" Height="64" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="Rubros" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="White" />
                    </BulletDecorator>
                </Expander.Header>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                    <Label Margin="20,5,5,5" Foreground="white" Content="----------"/>
                    <Label Margin="20,5,5,5" Foreground="white" Content="----------------"/>
                    <Label Margin="20,5,5,5" Foreground="white" Content="----------------"/>
                </WrapPanel>
            </Expander>

            <Expander Background="Teal">
                <Expander.Header>
                    <BulletDecorator>
                        <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                            <Image Width="64" Height="64" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" Text="Subrubros" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="White" />
                    </BulletDecorator>
                </Expander.Header>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <Label Margin="20,5,5,5" Foreground="white" Content="----------"/>
                    <Label Margin="20,5,5,5" Foreground="white" Content="-------------------"/>
                </WrapPanel>
            </Expander>
        </ListBox>
```

Any clues what's happening or what I am getting wrong with templates??

Comment: I cant get it working =(

Comment: Posted final answer with full explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change background of DockPanel, this will use Background property set in Expander in DockPanel. You have set it to Violet.

   ```
   <DockPanel Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
   ```
2. Change ToggleButton Content property to `<ToggleButton Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"`.
   This will show your Header content of Expander in ToggleButton. You have set it to 'Administrar Cuentas'.
3. Change control template of your Expander from

   ```
   <ToggleButton.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
     </ControlTemplate>
   ```

   to

   ```
    <ToggleButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
           <Border BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="24">
                   <ContentPresenter/>
           </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ToggleButton.Template>
   ```

You are trying to put TextBlock of your Header content(set in XAML) inside TextBlock(template). Now, after change TextBlock of Header content will appear within border. Note here `<ContentPresenter/>` is pointing to 
Header.

4. These changes are enough. I have also changed Horizontal properties of Expander like : 
   `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"`

/////////// Changed ResourceDictionary //////////

```
 <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Style x:Key="CustomListBox" TargetType="ListBox">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded"
                Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected,
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" />
        </Style>
        <ScrollViewer x:Key="Scroller">
            <ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility>
                Auto
            </ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                <ItemsPresenter/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="CustomExpander" TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                <DockPanel Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ToggleButton
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                    Background="Teal"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                    Foreground="WhiteSmoke"
                    FontSize="12"
                    Name="Header"
                    Padding="1"
                    >
                        <ToggleButton.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                <Border BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="24">
                                    <ContentPresenter/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ToggleButton.Template>
                    </ToggleButton>
                    <ContentPresenter
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                    Name="ExpandSite"
                    Visibility="Visible"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have touched only your ResourceDictionary, and added background to your second expander.

[Output after modifying your styles only.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4vsq.png)